# MongoLab Scientific Notation in Table view

Tags: mlab

I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to format table view definitions. Here's what I have:

What I see on document in collection:

```
{
some_number: 1111111111
}
```

View definition:

```
{
"Number": "some_number"
}
```

What I see in table view:

```
Number
1.111111111E9
```

While they're technically equivalent, I am wondering if there's a way to stop MongoLab form turning it into scientific notation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MongoLab support as of July 14th, 2015, they currently do not support user formatting numbers. They have since fixed the scientific notation issue and numbers now show with commas (eg 6000546 will show as 6,000,564.0000 or something of the likes). The workaround for this problem is to store the data values as strings rather than numbers.